# Xcode - test two different versions of project on one device

Tags: xcode

For AB testing, I have two different versions of my Xcode project that i want to load on the same device.  Is there a way to load the two versions without having to create another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have two different versions of the same app on your device.

So create a second target within your Xcode app (maybe duplicating the first one), and then all you need to do is have a second Info.plist file which has a *different* bundle ID.  Everything else (i.e. the files that get compiled, the settings that are set for the target, etc.) will be the same.

The Bundle ID is what matters to your iDevice, so you can have multiple similarly named apps on it but they must have different bundle ID's in each case.